# How to take Icons data type in list in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to set a list of Icons where I can pass in a loop : Example

```
final  List<Icons> iconsImage = 
    [Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied),
    Icon(Icons.home),
    Icon(Icons.drafts),
    Icon(Icons.backspace)];
```

But this completely wrong as. the name "Icons" is not any type.
Can someone suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Icon` as type

```
final  List<Icon> iconsImage = 
    [Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied),
    Icon(Icons.home),
    Icon(Icons.drafts),
    Icon(Icons.backspace)];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up on this page looking for a way to create a list of the data associated with the icons. If anyone else is here for that, this is how you create a list of `iconData`.

```
final  List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
    Icons.home,
    Icons.drafts,
    Icons.backspace
];
```

Self-explanatory but I didn't know what the type the `Icons.home` was. It is `IconData`.